# How to add value into variable in if for loop condition in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, if-statement, increment

I'm new to C programming, I'm confused why my code not working. So I have case where every time the value is true on IF statement, it will add 1 value to variable and either if false too, it will add value.

```
int i,n,nilai,kelulusan,lulus,tidaklulus;
   printf("Berapa banyak nilai yang ingin dimasukkan?: ");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
       printf("Masukkan nilai: ");
       scanf("%d",&nilai);
       if(nilai>=60)
       {
           printf("Nilai ini lulus\n");
           lulus++;
           printf("\n");
       }
       else
       {
           printf("Nilai ini tidak lulus\n");
           tidaklulus++;
           printf("\n");
       }
   }
   printf("Dari %d nilai, ada %d yang lulus, dan %d yang tidak lulus.",n,kelulusan,tidaklulus);
```

The input is going to be like this for example:

```
Berapa banyak nilai yang ingin dimasukkan?: 3
Masukkan nilai: 2
Nilai ini tidak lulus

Masukkan nilai: 2
Nilai ini tidak lulus

Masukkan nilai: 60
Nilai ini lulus

Dari 3 nilai, ada 10425344 yang lulus, dan 2 yang tidak lulus.
```

I get wrong output

```
Dari 3 nilai, ada **10425344** yang lulus, dan 2 yang tidak lulus.
```

The right output should be like this

```
Dari 3 nilai, ada 1 yang lulus, dan 2 yang tidak lulus.
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: You should turn up compiler warnings. You should get a warning about using `lulus` without assigning a value before. Same for `tidaklulus`. You are using them without initialization and incrementing them causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: You never initialize the values of the `nilai,kelulusan,lulus,tidaklulus` variables. They could start with any values.

Comment: Thankyou so much for answering, its really work now:D. I spent 1 hour for finding the solution:)

Comment: Anticipating your next question: `for (i = 1;i <= n; i++)`: rather use `for (i=0; i< n; i++)` this is more idiomatic and it is more natural when you want to store your data in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected that code. Works as Lord desired.  Has all mistakes marked with comments.
Anyway I recommend using **-Wall** flag for your compiler. It will turn **on all warnings**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i; //"Initialized" by for(...) loop
  int n,nilai; //"Initialized" by scanf
  int lulus=0,tidaklulus=0;   //Definitly need initialization
  //You define `kelulusan` and than print it with out using it storage potential?
  /*Use
    #define kelulusan ⟦any value⟧
  if you need a compile-time constant*/
  
  printf("Berapa banyak nilai yang ingin dimasukkan?: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
     printf("Masukkan nilai: ");
     scanf("%d",&nilai);
     if(nilai>=60)
     {
         printf("Nilai ini lulus\n");
         lulus++;
         printf("\n");
     }
     else
     {
         printf("Nilai ini tidak lulus\n");
         tidaklulus++;
         printf("\n");
     }
  }
  //Asumed that `kelulusan` was in place of `lulus` and corrected that.
  printf("Dari %d nilai, ada %d yang lulus,"
   "dan %d yang tidak lulus.",n, lulus,tidaklulus
  );
    
}
```